# process.exit(0) in cloud function finishes with status: 'crash'

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm terminating cloud function with `process.exit(0)`. It does terminate my function but throws this line in the logs:

> finished with status: 'crash'

Does this mean that such a function completion has some pitfalls? Such a strong word in logs is a little scary)

Comment: I don't believe functions are supposed to cause the process as a whole to exit. What problem are you solving by calling `process.exit(0);` ?

Comment: My cloud function monitors changes in Firestore database and should stop and exit on meeting several conditions. Calling process.exit(0); is the fastest way for me to do this. Surely not the cleanest way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exiting the process is not at all what you're supposed to do.  I suggest reviewing the [documentation on function termination](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/nodejs-runtime#signal-termination).  If you have a background function (trigger), you must return a promise that indicates when any async work is complete.  For HTTP functions, you must send a response and return.  Nowhere will you see any documentation or examples that involve exiting the process, as that kills the node process that would normally serve many requests during its lifetime.

Comment: Just to confirm. Event triggered function is considered as a background function in documentation?

Comment: If it's not driven directly by an HTTP request, it's a background function.